# Restricting numbers in mongo schema

Tags: validation, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I have a "due" field in my mongoose model for bills. The field represents a day of the month, a number from 1-31.

How can I change this validation to prevent numbers higher than 31 being accepted?

```
due: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
    validate: {
      validator: function (v) {
        return /^(3[01]|[12][0-9]|[1-9])/.test(v)
      },
      message: props => `$(props.value) is not a valid calendar day`
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `regex` is not valid. If you type `33` it still will match on first `3` etc.

try: `/(1|2)([0-9])|(3)(0|1)|^([0-9]){1}$/.test(v)`

```
due: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
    validate: {
      validator: function (v) {
        return /(1|2)([0-9])|(3)(0|1)|^([0-9]){1}$/.test(v)
      },
      message: props => `$(props.value) is not a valid calendar day`
    }
  }
```

You can [test the regEx here](https://regex101.com/r/QU01aV/1) and also see the detailed explanation as well.